# Start vscode debug passing node env variable to use with npm debug module

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code

I would like to use the useful npm module [debug](https://www.npmjs.com/package/debug) in a Node app.
To use `debug` module I have to start vscode debugging by passing an environment variable (e.g. DEBUG=info)

I tried to add the following into launch.json in the configurations section:

```
 "env": {
            "DEBUG": "info"
        }
```

But I received an error like: 'Error: write EPIPE...'

While starting the Node App as `DEBUG=info node index` it runs flawlessly.